# How to display full message of push notification in appcelerator

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have problem with my notification development (android). The notification message not display full message. How to make it can expand same like whatsapp notification on the phone.

Thanks

[example my current notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyLUi.png)

Answer (score 1):

The length of the push notification text is limited and you can't bypass that. To display the full message, you could send the full text with the push message as data. But keep in mind that there is an overall size limit for push message data.

Or if you want to do it like whatsapp, store the messages in your DB and let the app fetch/sync the messages from there. There's no need to transfer the full message with the push message then.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the size of the push notification message using following code

```
String longmsg="";

.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
         .bigText(longmsg))
```

Answer (score 0):

For local notification/ In app notification, there is one property "style" for Titanium.Android.Notificationstyle.
If you set value of style property to "Titanium.Android.BigTextStyle", you can able to expand your local notification.
style property will not work for notification from server.

Answer (score -1):

You'll be able to use the BigTextStyle API for this in Titanium 5.4 (scheduled for July):

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20066

Comment: will this work for push notifications or just local notifications?

Comment: For my understanding it's is for push notification.

Comment: It seems appcelerator is not interested in implementing this for push notifications https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20126?focusedCommentId=371647&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-371647